# Can only select certain polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, vector, select

I have only one vector layer on my map, and it's not letting me select some polygons. For instance, this is what happens when I try to select a certain polygon (the yellow outline with the blue star inside it).
[image]

[image]

Those polygons aren't missing or anything-- when I fill them in, everything gets filled correctly:
[image]

Why can't I select this polygon?

Comment: It looks like they're overlapping. When you click to select, do you get the little icon pop up near the mouse that lets you switch your selection? Also, if you do a select-by-rectangle, does it select both of them?

Comment: When I just click once, nothing pops up. But when I do a select-by-rectangle it does select both of them.

Comment: If this is a shapefile, you should probably verify the topology, since selection algorithms are dependent on proper ring topology.

Comment: Remove sbn and sbx components of shapefile.

Comment: @FelixIP this is a feature class in a geodatabase, not a shapefile, so I can't do that.

Comment: @Vince yeah I just verified it and for some reason there are a shit-ton of overlaps...No clue how that happened since this is just a vector that was auto-generated based on the raster below. I'll do Create Feature on them all and hopefully that fixes it.